# How to remove "mvn" from windows 10 CMD

Tags: maven, cmd

I installed node.js and run following command

```
npm install mvn
```

now, mvn command is binding to node.js even I uninstalled it.

```
>mvn
'node' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
```

Actually, I need to binding "mvn" to maven which I already setted into system PATH.

but, it doesn't work (still points to node.js)

Please help.

Comment: Are you trying this command on a regular terminal or command prompt, or using *NodeJs Command Prompt*?

Comment: I tried on regular terminal (CMD) or git bash. Neither works.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a "mvn.cmd" file under the following folder

```
C:\Users\Your name\AppData\Roaming\npm
```

Simply delete this file.